# Android application works in emulator but failed in device

Tags: java, android, eclipse

my android application works fine in emulator, but when i install the .apk and run, it said "Unfortunately 'application' has stopped"

this is the androidmanifest.xml

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.baliweather"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity android:name=".Prakiraan"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Update"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>
      <activity android:name=".Info"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>
</application>
```

error log:

> 09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394): at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:519)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:489)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:579)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:827)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at com.android.baliweather.MyParser.xmlParsing(MyParser.java:43)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at com.android.baliweather.Prakiraan$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(Prakiraan.java:60)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at com.android.baliweather.Prakiraan$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(Prakiraan.java:1)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
>   09-02 15:25:01.372: E/AndroidRuntime(16394):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please post your logcat error message

Comment: i see that you are using the L preview here during project setup were you able to get compile with api 21[L preview] as i was not able to see this option.

Comment: how to show the log from the device?

Comment: connect your phone to pc in USB Debugging mode and run project in eclipse and see Logcat

Comment: i have post the error log

Answer (score 1):

```
 android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Pretty self-explainatory, right? You're doing network tasks (HTTP Requests and such) on the UI thread. You should run it in a separate thread.

```
    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.interrupted();
                }
            }
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
            txt.setText("Executed"); // txt.setText(result);
            // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
            // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
```

Above an example.

Make it a inner class from your activity

Answer (score 0):

Once i am having the same issue  after uploading it to `playstore`.

When app crashes you can see two buttons, **force stop / OK and report**. Click on `report button` and there you will find various tabs. In one of the tabs you will get stacktrace. and then you can know where your error is...

And one time clean the project and recreate an apk and then check also..